# Getting exception in Transport.send method

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get an email in my forget password module bt this is the exception i am getting.
Appreciation in advance!

```html
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuX
534-5.7.14 fAu8nfa4SHWaBUpnzeQrQedgOXyBxgzjsvxAAW_wa2GmTocRiAyuXMlnw3bb5AS7k6ba_S
534-5.7.14 tr6DS1yYByctQzldQZuuh5ToXwgw0IxF4oMok_CVkyMIR3qd9-aNNyKNu5mOICXlEVohx2
534-5.7.14 dd3x_kN96vc2_uRI2HWub0DqwbYh2VsoiZgxs8plhJCO76Ct55efXd9a6DK7HQnCXmzQRX
534-5.7.14 gTaEEKIaWkQOVPrl1eIjiv2HG2cMQ> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 85sm41450849pfq.6 - gsmtp
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:892)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

Comment: Please log in via your web browser and then try again.

Comment: i m log in via my web brower

Comment: Have you read the suggestions from the stated support page?

Comment: Have you authorized smtp connection to your gmail account ? https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: Bt initially it was working right even i didn't need to connect smtp to my gmail account??

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Review question again i added the coding part.. Whats wrong in this ??

Comment: Gmail is trying to make sure your account isn't being hijacked or abused.  They want you to login with your browser from the same machine that is trying to send the mail.  Try going to [this link](https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuXfAu8nfa4SHWaBUpnzeQrQedgOXyBxgzjsvxAAW_wa2GmTocRiAyuXMlnw3bb5AS7k6ba_Str6DS1yYByctQzldQZuuh5ToXwgw0IxF4oMok_CVkyMIR3qd9-aNNyKNu5mOICXlEVohx2dd3x_kN96vc2_uRI2HWub0DqwbYh2VsoiZgxs8plhJCO76Ct55efXd9a6DK7HQnCXmzQRXgTaEEKIaWkQOVPrl1eIjiv2HG2cMQ) and login.